Spring Boot application starting but url giving 404 in postaman
I am creating a new Spring Boot application to maintain the phonebook records, However when I am running the application in Tomcat server, it is giving this exception
here is my springBootApplication class ,controller, service, and repository classes with pom.xml
Application.class
package com.project.phone.phonebook;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

PhoneController
 package com.project.phone.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.project.phone.Entity.PhoneRecord;
import com.project.phone.Service.PhoneService;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;


@RestController // shorthand for @Controller and @ResponseBody rolled together
@RequestMapping("phone/api/phone")
public class PhoneController {

    @Autowired
    PhoneService phoneService;
    
    @GetMapping("/start")
    public String getMethodName() {
        return "start";
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value ="/getAll", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<PhoneRecord>> getAllRecords(){
        
        List<PhoneRecord> listOfRecords= phoneService.getAllRecords();
        return (ResponseEntity<List<PhoneRecord>>) listOfRecords;
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PhoneRecord> saveRecord(@RequestBody PhoneRecord phone){
        
        PhoneRecord newPhone= phoneService.saveNewRecord(phone);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newPhone, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        
    } 
}

phoneService class
    package com.project.phone.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.project.phone.Entity.PhoneRecord;
import com.project.phone.Repository.PhoneRepo;

@Component
public class PhoneService {

    @Autowired
    PhoneRepo phoneRepo;
    
    public List<PhoneRecord> getAllRecords(){
    
        List<PhoneRecord> phoneRecords = phoneRepo.getAll();            
        return phoneRecords;
    }
    
    public PhoneRecord saveNewRecord(PhoneRecord phone) {
        
        PhoneRecord pRecord = phoneRepo.save(phone);
        return pRecord;
        
    }
}

PhoneRepo
package com.project.phone.Repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.project.phone.Entity.PhoneRecord;

@Repository public interface PhoneRepo extends JpaRepository<PhoneRecord, Integer> {

public List<PhoneRecord> getAll();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public PhoneRecord save(PhoneRecord phone);
    

}
Pom.xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.phoneBook</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo.phonebook</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo.phonebook</name>
    <description>phone book project for spring</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


show your class with @SpringBootApplication annotation

Added, now the problem is solve, but still not able to access the get url, could you please help in this?

@AnkitRege  Could you share the exception from the stack trace?

there is no error/exception in stack trace

your SpringBoot application will only scan packages com.project.phone.phonebook and child packages of that package - it won't by default scan sibling packages. You should restructure you application so that relevant packages are child packages of com.project.phone.phonebook OR explciitly configure @ComponentScan which packages are to be scanned

@AnkitRege Like Asgarov mentioned, all other packages(Controller/Service/Repository) should be inside com.project.phone.phonebook. Also, in the repository, you can replace getAll() with findAll() method as it is the standard method provided by JPA to return all the available records. Secondly, there is no need to define a save() method as JpaRepository already includes a save() method for persisting entities.

(1) Check your tomcat/logs/ catalina.out (2) if your spring boot application is config right and run as web application ,  your log will see:  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.3), (3) or you just see [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/your-path/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/webapps/YOURAPPNAME.war] has finished in [820] ms (4) I guess , your log is (3) not (2)

insert a screenshot of the url you have added in the postman

@thomsonIgnesious , i checked and found the issue,
